# Unable to create wp-content/uploads

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to import content from a Wordpress installation I have. But when I try to import it, I find the following error:

[image]

I'm working on Plesk 12, and I went to folder permissions. All users I have are supposed to have full permissions...

I followed steps [here](https://support.managed.com/kb/a642/how-to-fix-permissions-on-your-site-through-the-plesk-control-panel.aspx) to add full permissions.

Any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: Ensure the directories have the proper owner. Check out the following post (but be careful with their instructions as it broke one user's site): http://www.ryanbelanger.com/wordpress-file-permissions/

Comment: All of them are full control, and I'm a bit afraid of the post you said...